# Set all texbox readonly

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, code-behind

How to set onload all TextBox readonly from masterpage code behind ?

I tried the below code, but it does not work:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
   {
     if (c is TextBox)
        ((TextBox)c).ReadOnly = true;
   }
}
```

thank's

Comment: You missed controls in controls:  `void foo(Control p){foreach(Control c in p.Controls) if( c is TextBox ) ((TextBox)c).ReadOnly = true; else foo(c);}`  Not that I really recommend that.  Far better to know what's on your page than search in `.Controls`.

Answer (score 2):

Ebyrob and I had the same thought, added a null-reference protection and check to see if the control has children (reduces calls).

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SetReadonly(this);
    }
    private void SetReadonly(Control c)
    {
        if (c == null)
        {
            return; 
        }
        foreach (Control item in c.Controls)
        {
            if (item.HasChildren)
            {
                SetReadonly(c);
            }
            else if (c is TextBox)
            {
                ((TextBox)c).ReadOnly = true;
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: @Amid, make sure you have 'using System.Windows.Forms', Control.HasChildren has been part of the .Net framework since 1.1 [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.haschildren(v=vs.71).aspx) and is still in the framework as of 4.5. This specific example was tested in 4.0.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  foreach (TextBox textbox in this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
   {
        textbox.ReadOnly = true;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this. I test this and work fine

```
 private void SetReadonly(Control c)
    {
        if (c == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        foreach (Control item in c.Controls)
        {

            if (item is TextBox)
            {
                ((TextBox)item).ReadOnly = true;
            }

            else if (item.HasControls())
            {
                SetReadonly(item);
            }

        }
    }
```